# Why Dynamic Refresh Rate doesn't show up on Windows 11 setting?

Tags: windows

Below image is my PC information. My graphic card is GeFore RTX 2060 and I just update to latest driver version from NVIDIA website. My driver model WDDM version up from 2.7 to 3.1.
My monitor is ASUS Game TUF VG27B.

But I don't know my setting still not show up Dynamic Refresh Rate

[image: pc information]

[image][image]